# Reference on stages of heavy ion collisions in particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, heavy-ion, quark-gluon-plasma, hadronization

Is there any reference (book/review article etc.) where the physics of heavy ion collisions is overviewed?

To be absolutely clear about things, I am looking for a introductory review which covers the physics aspects of the progression through the following stages

- stable nuclei
- fireball
- quark-gluon plasma formation
- (cooling)
- hadronization
- hadron interactions and decay
- final observable particles (leptons, photons etc.)

with special emphasis on parameters like

1. time for these stages,
2. relevant temperatures,
3. particle densities etc.

Apparently all the literature I have scanned through talks about bits and parts, a comprehensive big picture is unclear to me largely.

Comment: In retrospect I guess if the first list is going to be a list at all, it should have been the numbered list, and the other list a bulleted list. Oh well. Something to consider if somebody edits the question again.

Answer (score 1):

If someone stumbles across this question here some links:

Very general, about big questions in the field from 2018:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04801

More physics in here, by U. Heinz from 2013:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2826

Very nice review paper, linking to many established papers (2016):
https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08694

A PhD thesis, covering what you might look for in the first few pages (2014):
https://etd.ohiolink.edu/pg_10?::NO:10:P10_ETD_SUBID:97415